# How to append a string to one specific line and remove a string from another specific line in a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to append and remove some values in my property file.

This is my property file:

```
## Portal.Group=Security Role:Extranet Role
Portal.Advisor=MAS:MAS,SRM:SRM,SIV:SIV,ADN:ADN,IFA:IFA,ACC:ACC,BSR:BSR,TRD:TRD,VOC:VOC,VFC:VFC,VFA:VFA,BDD:BDD,EFA:EFA,EAC:EAC,DDM:DDM,PFM:PFM,PDA:PDA,PAM:PAM
Portal.Customer=CUS:CUS,CTU:CTU,CTM:CTM,AMR:AMR,FSS:FSS,GSV:GSV
TC.SecurityRoles=MAS,SRM,SIV,ADN,IFA,ACC,EFA,EAC,CUS,DDM,CTU,CTM,PFM,PDA,PAM
```

I want to append this value `COA:COA,ALW:ALW` on line starting with `Portal.Advisor`.

I want remove this value `CTU:CTU,CTM:CTM` from line starting with `Portal.Customer`.

I achieved this goal on Linux by using **sed** command, but now I need it in a Windows based script.

Comment: Great! Go ahead and tell us how it's going! Or do you want us to help you? In this case, show effort and tell us what you have tried yet.

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't mentioned or cannot use [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)?

Comment: You asked this question already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904052/property-file-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First possible solution for this task using only Windows command interpreter internal commands:

```
@echo off
if not exist "PropertyFile.txt" goto :EOF

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PropertyFile=PropertyFile.txt"
set "TempFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
del "%TempFile%" 2>nul

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%PropertyFile%") do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    if /I "!Line:~0,15!" == "Portal.Advisor=" (
        set "Line=!Line!,COA:COA,ALW:ALW"
    ) else if /I "!Line:~0,16!" == "Portal.Customer=" (
        set "Line=!Line:CTU:CTU,CTM:CTM,=!"
    )
    echo !Line!>>"%TempFile%"
)

move /Y "%TempFile%" "%PropertyFile%" 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 del "%TempFile%"
endlocal
```

Second possible solution using [JREPL.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid for appending and removing the strings in the property file using two regular expression replaces:

```
@echo off
if not exist "PropertyFile.txt" goto :EOF
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" goto :EOF

call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "^(Portal.Advisor=.+)$" "$1,COA:COA,ALW:ALW" /I /F "PropertyFile.txt" /O -
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "^(Portal.Customer=.*)CTU:CTU,CTM:CTM," "$1" /I /F "PropertyFile.txt" /O -
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) explaining `>>` and `2>nul`.

Comment: I tried with the second solution using the  JREPL.bat